# Packer azure-arm vhd build fails with authentication error

Tags: azure, azure-storage, packer

I am trying to build a VHD with packer. I followed one of the basic examples, but the build fails right after deleting the temporary resource group with the following message:

```
==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:                   
--> azure-arm: storage: service returned error: StatusCode=403, ErrorCode=AuthenticationFailed, ErrorMessage=Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

Here is my template:

```
{
  "builders": [{
    "type": "azure-arm",

    "client_id": "myclientid",
    "client_secret": "myclientsecret",
    "resource_group_name": "packer",
    "storage_account": "packerstorage",
    "subscription_id": "mysubscriptionid",
    "tenant_id": "mytenantid",

    "capture_container_name": "images",
    "capture_name_prefix": "packerimage",

    "os_type": "Linux",
    "image_publisher": "Canonical",
    "image_offer": "UbuntuServer",
    "image_sku": "14.04.4-LTS",

    "azure_tags": {
      "dept": "engineering"
    },

    "location": "East US",
    "vm_size": "Standard_A2"
  }],

 "provisioners": [{
        "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .Path }}'",
        "inline": [
                "/usr/sbin/waagent -force -deprovision+user && export HISTSIZE=0 && sync"
        ],
        "inline_shebang": "/bin/sh -x",
        "type": "shell"
  }]
}
```

I've tried with v1 storage, v2 storage, lrs redundancy, but at this point I am not sure what I am missing. I created the storage account under the same resource group set in `resource_group_name` and verified that the application I am using has the owner role inherited from my subscription.

Comment: This packer file works for me, Does that storage account create in east us?

Comment: Hi @JasonYe-MSFT correct, the storage account is on the same location

Answer (score 1):

The issue come from my packer installation using the arch linux package. Using the compiled binary everything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.